# TypeError from admin change page

Tags: python, django

I have an error when I'm trying to access an object on my admin.

TypeError at /admin/core/order/11/change/
**str** returned non-string (type NoneType)

**str** returned non-string (type NoneType)

```
9               {% for field in line %}
10                  <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="fieldBox{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
11                      {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
12                      {% if field.is_checkbox %}
13                          {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
14                      {% else %}
15                          {{ field.label_tag }}
16                          {% if field.is_readonly %}
17                              <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
18                          {% else %}
19                              {{ field.field }}
20                          {% endif %}
21                      {% endif %}
22                      {% if field.field.help_text %}
23                          <div class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</div>
24                      {% endif %}
25                  </div>
26              {% endfor %}
27          </div>
28      {% endfor %}
29  </fieldset>
```

my models

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

# Create your models here.
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True) 
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField()    
    slug = models.SlugField()
    
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:product", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
    
    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("core:add_to_cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def remove_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("core:remove_from_cart", kwargs={
        'slug': self.slug
    })



class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
    on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.item)

    def get_total_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.price

    
    def get_total_discount_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.discount_price


    def get_amount_saved(self):
        return self.get_total_item_price() - self.get_total_discount_item_price()


    def get_final_price(self):
        if self.item.discount_price:
            return self.get_total_discount_item_price()
        return self.get_total_item_price()


class  Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
     on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey('BillingAddress',
     on_delete= models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    payment = models.ForeignKey('Payment',
     on_delete= models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
 

    def get_total(self):
        total= 0
        for order_item in self.items.all():
            total += order_item.get_final_price()
        return total



class BillingAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
     on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    appartment_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = CountryField(multiple = False)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    

    def __str__(self):
        self.user.username



class Payment(models.Model):
    stripe_charge_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.FloatField()    
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

i log in the admin pannel add my credentials, and try to pick on of the order freshly made once clicke on it it retirn this error
TypeError at /admin/core/order/11/change/
**str** returned non-string (type NoneType)

i cannot have access on the admin what should i do please?

Comment: Please include the full traceback and the `Order` admin class

Comment: Im sorry im new at programming the full traceback you saidf?

Comment: Yeah, the full error that comes out in the console. It tells us what's being executed in the run up to the error. Combined with your admin class, that's how you find what's wrong

Comment: I have updated the best way i could